# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  1am UTC on the 24th / 8pm EST on the 23rd - now!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Thursday the 24th at 1am UTC, *or 8pm EST on the 23rd.***

**[(view in other timezones)](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=24&year=2011&hour=1&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[join the chat now!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/300/elu-town-hall-chat)**

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 22nd-24th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=english.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/300/elu-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript and a summary will be available.

Answer (score 0):

As with the other town hall chats, I will be creating a "digest" version for the English Language & Usage Town Hall Chat. This will be posted as one large Meta question. The digest will contain all the questions and their answers, with none of the other conversation from the room.

For more information, please see [the meta post about Town Hall Digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests). Or for an example, look at the [AskUbuntu Town Hall Digest](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/948/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) or the [Gaming Town Hall Digest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1759/2252).

You can also discuss these digests with me in chat, in [the Town Hall Discussion room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

**A giant thank you to Rebecca for doing the digest for me!** It has just been posted to Meta:

#### [The Town Hall Chat Digest](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/775/2259)